# How to Determine which subsets of R^3 is a subspace of R^3.

Tags: linear-algebra

I have some questions about determining which subset is a subspace of R^3. Here are the questions:

```
a) {(x,y,z)∈ R^3 :x = 0} 
b) {(x,y,z)∈ R^3 :x + y = 0} 
c) {(x,y,z)∈ R^3 :xz = 0} 
d) {(x,y,z)∈ R^3 :y ≥ 0}
e) {(x,y,z)∈ R^3 :x = y = z}
```

I am familiar with the conditions that must be met in order for a subset to be a subspace:

1. 0 ∈ R^3
2. u+v ∈ R^3
3. ku ∈ R^3

When I tried solving these, I thought i was doing it correctly but I checked the answers and I got them wrong. Can someone walk me through any of these problems? I've tried watching videos but find myself confused. Any help would be great!Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it like an algorithm. I'll do the first, you'll do the rest. I want to analyze $$I = \{(x,y,z) \in \Bbb R^3 \ : \ x = 0\}$$

The first condition is ${\bf 0} \in I$. Is it? Well, ${\bf 0} = (0,0,0)$ has the first coordinate $x = 0$, so yes, ${\bf 0} \in I$.

The second condition is ${\bf v},{\bf w} \in I \implies {\bf v}+{\bf w} \in I$. Now, I take two elements, ${\bf v}$ and ${\bf w}$ in $I$. I know that their first components are zero, that is, ${\bf v} = (0, v_2, v_3)$ and ${\bf w} = (0, w_2, w_3)$. Is their sum in $I$? Test it! $${\bf v} + {\bf w} = (0 + 0, v_2+w_2,v_3+w_3) = (0 , v_2+w_2,v_3+w_3)$$
Since the first component is zero, then ${\bf v} + {\bf w} \in I$.

The third condition is $k \in \Bbb R$, ${\bf v} \in I \implies k{\bf v} \in I$. Then, I take ${\bf v} \in I$. I know that it's first component is zero, that is, ${\bf v} = (0,v_2, v_3)$. Is $k{\bf v} \in I$? Compute it, like this:
$$k{\bf v} = k(0,v_2,v_3) = (k0,kv_2, kv_3) = (0, kv_2, kv_3)$$
Is its first component zero? Yes, it is, then $k{\bf v} \in I$, and hence $I \leq \Bbb R^3$. Think alike for the rest.

Comment: Thank you! I think I understand it now based on the way you explained it. I finished the rest and if its not too much trouble, would you mind checking my solutions (I only have solution to first one): a)YES b)YES c)YES d) NO(fails multiplication property) e) YES

Comment: Look at **(c)** more closely.  Do you see how closure under sums (your second property of a subspace) can fail?

Comment: Everything is ok except for **c)**. The problem is in closure under sums, as Sammy Black said.

Comment: That's right!I looked at it more carefully. I made v=(1,v2,0) and w=(1,w2,0) and thats why I originally thought it was ok(for some reason I thought that both v & w had to be the same). What I tried after was v=(1,v2,0) and w=(0,w2,1), and like you both said, it failed. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

a) Take two vectors $u$ and $v$ from that set. $y = u+v$ satisfies $y_x = u_x + v_x = 0 + 0 = 0$. Take $k \in \mathbb{R}$, the vector $k v$ satisfies $(k v)_x = k v_x = k 0 = 0$. Finally, the vector $(0,0,0)^T$ has $x$-component equal to $0$ and is therefore also part of the set.

Can you take it from here ?